# Do these 2 LINQ join queries achieve the same thing

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, join

I want to join 2 tables and get some data out of it using LINQ. here are the 2 ways in which i can do this

```
1. 

 var orders = from order in db.Order
                 from user in db.User
                 where order.UserId == user.UserId
                 select order;

2.
    var result = from order in db.Order
                 join user in db.user
                 on order.UserId equals user.userId
                 select order
```

are these queries one and the same? are they different in any way?

Comment: I know in SQL they are both executed (query plan) the same so I would assume you would get the same performance whether linq did the transition to the join syntax or let it fall through to the data provider / db to do it.

Comment: Also note that when training new developers I always recommend using only the join syntax in production code.  It is cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: As another data point, I find the first query easier to read and comprehend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are same. First syntax is implicit, second one is explicit join syntax.

Refer to wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) for both type of syntax.

Comment: so absolutely no impact on performance? as @tsells said, 2nd option is more cleaner code i guess